# How to calculate the number of minutes between the arrival of each command?

Tags: android, time

my android app receives commands from server across a socket.
How to calculate the number of minutes between the arrival of each command?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gENVB6tjq_M

Answer (score 1):

Use [System.currentTimeMillis()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) each time you get a command.  Subtract, then divide by the number of milliseconds in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Then just some simple subtraction should get you your answer.